# Add an icon to input text as a non part of it

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `bootstrap 2.3.2`, and I have a form that contains an `input text`.
In the right of `the input text` I have an icon.

[image]

And this is the html for that `input text` :

```
<div class="right-inner-addon">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Recherche un article" class="search-query">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</div>
```

And this is it's style :

```
.right-inner-addon input {
    padding-right: 30px;    
}
.right-inner-addon i {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

The problem is that when I type some long text, this text is written under that `search icon` :

[image]

I want when I write a long text to not be written under the `search icon`, how can I do that ?

Comment: dont use a transparent png, or put the img in a div which has the same backgroundcolor.

why didnt you make a div with rounded shape add the search icon and then put the input in it which isnt as long that it can reach the search icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the Bootstrap 2.3.2 version and use below CSS code to place the search icon at right side.

```
.right-inner-addon{position:relative;}
.right-inner-addon input {
    padding-right: 30px; 
    height:30px;
}
.right-inner-addon i {
    padding: 7px 12px;
    padding-left: 11px;
   position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
  right:0
   
}
.icon-search {
    background-position: -36px 3px;
}
```

and the HTML code look like this.

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-left form-search">
  <div class="right-inner-addon">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Recherche un article" class="search-query">
  <i class="icon-search"></i>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is the working Demo. https://refork.codicode.com/351.cod